# Mesh vs LineRenderer Performance

Tags: unity, performance, mesh

I've created a script, which is drawing a line along a bezier curve, so that I can animate whatever I want with lines, mostly for UI purposes. For the moment I'm using a line renderer, which works, but the performance is not that great in my opinion. So I was wondering if there are actually some better methods to draw lines, like simply creating a mesh along the path I've got.

Comment: Take a look at VectorLines:  http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=VectorLine

Comment: Looks great, but looks like it is "just" 2D?

Comment: Yeah,this will not work in 3D.   Might want to add that in your question if that is a requirement.

Comment: Nevermind, this helps me anyway a lot, I just noticed that it doesn't look like 3D :)

Comment: Here is more information on GL.Lines:  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html

Comment: I wouldn't bet on this but I think the reason LineRenderers were originally put in Unity is that people where tired of re-producing same code to build line meshes by hand. So I don't think there would be a big difference if you use LineRenderers. Again - I'm just supposing, I'm not a Unity representative or anything.